# Spring Cloud Stream: Get input destination name from output binder

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Hopefully the title kind of says it all. I am writing a custom Spring Cloud Stream binder which operates as a Producer only (specifically it is streaming data into a database).

For ingest API reasons, I would like to be able to capture and distinguish the sources of the data (i.e., get the Input Destination names) for the specific binding, but cannot see anyway to do that from the standard binder samples out there, as typically the producers get access to their producer properties, and consumers get their consumer properties.

For example, my *application.yml* looks something like:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        data-in-0:
          destination: queue0
          binder: message-broker
        data-out-0:
          destination: tableA    # both sources feed the same table
          binder: some-database
        data-in-1:
          destination: queue1
          binder: message-broker
        data-out-1:
          destination: tableA    # both sources feed the same table
          binder: some-database
```

Programatically I would like to obtain the string values `queue0` and `queue1` from within the `MessageHandler` so that I can use this information during insertion to effectively identify where a given `Message<?>` instance originated from. And note: I am writing the *binder* implementation, so I cannot do anything clever in processor.

Comment: Which inbound binder are you using? The RabbitMQ and Kafka binders add source information to the message headers, not sure about others.